# Rack error with capybara/sinatra test... Doesn't seem to get the Sinatra app passed on

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra, capybara, rack

Trying to set up capybara/rspec for testing a simple sinatra app but keep getting a rack error.

hello.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "hello hello!"
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

spec/hello_spec.rb

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'hello.rb')

require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'

set :environment, :test

describe 'The Hello App' do

  include Capybara::DSL
  def setup
    Capybara.app = App
  end

  it "says hello when browsing /" do
    visit '/'
    page.should have_content('hello')
  end
end
```

Note, I also tried

```
  def setup
    Capybara.app = App.new
  end
```

Which produced the same error.

Error:

```
C:\Sites\misc\qrgen>bundle exec rspec
F

Failures:

  1) The Hello App says hello when browsing /
     Failure/Error: visit '/'
     ArgumentError:
       rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
     # ./spec/hello_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.374 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/hello_spec.rb:17 # The Hello App says hello when browsing /
```

Same error running with and without bundle exec. Any ideas?

Gemfile:

```
gem "sinatra"
gem "sinatra-contrib"
gem "sinatra-flash"
gem "slim"

gem "rspec"
gem "capybara"
gem "rack-test"
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope this is useful for someone else trying to set up testing from the Sinatra documentation.

Changing

```
def setup
  Capybara.app = App
end
```

to

```
Capybara.app = App
```

resolved the issue.

Comment: Might specify that `spec_helper.rb` is a good place to put this.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! FWIW, my app is set up as follows: `def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

Capybara.app = app`